# Why my webpage is loading without CSS in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

I am developing a website with CSS and JS modifications.

While testing the website, it is working fine in IE-8 and Firefox browsers. **But in Google Chrome and Safari the *web page is loading without CSS.***

I checked all the CSS paths on browser and all files are loading perfectly. But on the HTML page, these CSS files are not loading. So the webpage is displaying the contents without any CSS properties.

What changes do we need to make in Chrome and Safari in order to make the website work perfectly.

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless you give us a link to the problematic website. Also, have you checked the Resources tab in Chrome Developer Tools, if CSS files are actually loaded? Doesn't CSS contain any syntax errors?

Comment: sometimes having the CSS encoded in the wrong format makes some problems in webkit brwosers. Make sure your css is in UTF-8. PS: BB Codes does not work on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 2):

As for Chrome, it probably the cache. Chrome assumes that he has cache of the css that's why he will not load it. Deleting cache helps in troubleshooting unloaded css problems . Same things happens on Safari base on my experience with it